# Jquery REST_CLIENT_ERROR

Tags: java, jquery

I have created REST API through jersey API Jar, which gives desired result on web browser and test tool **fiddler**, but using same on restClient via jquery it moves to error part of  the code always.

**My Javacode:**

```
 package com.ugam.rest;

    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import com.ugam.pojo.Category;

    @Path("/level")
    public class ServiceHelper {

        @GET
        @Path("getPrice/{param}")
        @Produces("application/json")
        public Response getPrice(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

            String output = msg;

            return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

        }

        @GET
        @Path("/getCount/{param}")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Category getCount(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

            // String output ="This response is from getCount function" + msg;
            Category category = new Category();
            category.setCategory_Name("BGNIT");
            category.setCompetitor_Name("Amazon");
            category.setCount("33822");
            category.setFinal_price("25.78");
            // Response response = Response.status(200).entity(category).build();

            return category;
        }

    }
```

**Jquery Client** I have directly created in view for testing:

```
 <script type='text/javascrpt >
    $(window).load(function(){
         $.ajax(
                        {
                             dataType: 'json',
                            type:'GET',
                             url:'localhost:8080/HeatMapHelper/rest/level/getCount/Sid',

                             success: function(data)
                             {
                  document.writeln("Success in calling webService");
                             },
                             error: function(req,status,error)
                             {
                                 alert("error",req);
                     alert("Status",status);
                     document.writeln("Error while Calling REST WebService");

                             }
                        });  

                }); 
    </script>
```

So while accessing given  REST API(in java) link with REST_CLIENT in jquery it is  alert of "Error" and printing "Error while Calling REST WebService"

Comment: Why not print the actual error message?

Comment: I tried but it is coming blank only thing I can print is readystate and status of xmlhttprequest which is--> status=0 && readystate=4

Comment: Can you access that URL via the web browser?

Comment: yes with browser,fiddler,restclient in firefox I think I am missing either something while making request header

Comment: Try putting "http://" before "localhost" in the `url`.

Comment: I have already tried that

Comment: Finally putting html in my java project it starts working

Comment: Its a common cors issue saw my post after a long time so feel to update it .